# Form Registration not getting a error

Tags: php, html, mysql, forms, post

so i edited my code but still  unable to get the results part of code is responsible for reporting error that do not work too 
 i'm open to other ways of coding to do the work as long as it fits in the code  here comes the code

```
<?php

require 'core.inc.php';






if(!loggedIn()) {

//check mikunim ke tamame field ha dar form vojod darand va set shudan

if(isset($_POST['username'])&&isset($_POST['password'])&&isset($_POST['password_again'])&&isset($_POST['firstname'])&&isset($_POST['surname'])) {

    $username = $_POST['username'];
    $password = $_POST['password'];
    $password_again = $_POST['password_again'];
    $firsname = $POST['firstname'];
    $surename = $POST['surename'];



    //HALA CHECK MIKUNIM KHALI HASTAND YA NA

    if(!empty($username)&&!empty($password)&&!empty($email)&&!empty($firstname)&&!empty($surename)){
        echo 'ok' ;

    } else {

        echo ' All fields are required';

    }

}   

?>

<form action="register.php" method="POST">
Username:<br> <input type="text" name="username"><br> <br>
Password:<br> <input type="password" name="password"><br><br>
Password again:<br> <input type="password" name="password_again"><br><br>
Firstname:<br> <input type="text" name="firstname"><br><br>
Surname:<br> <input type="text" name="surename"><br><br>
<input type="submit" value="register">



</form>

<?php
    } else if (loggedIn()) {

    echo 'you \'re already logged in';
    }
```

i edited again now i get this

Notice: Undefined index: HTTP_REFERER

$http_referer = $_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']

i used this from tutorial

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it contains typos which will not help future users

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change this

```
$firsname = $POST['firstname'];
$surename = $POST['surename'];
```

to this:

```
$firstname = $_POST['firstname'];
$surename = $_POST['surename'];
```

Comment: what's the different?

Comment: You missed a **t** and **_**

Comment: thank you how can i prevent this to happen again? at least code gives me a error

Comment: Try with an ide (phpstorm, netbeans, eclipse, notepad++ too) that change color to unused vars and you can easily understand if a var is misspelled.